# Google Cloud Function Permalink

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, permalinks

I am using a Google Cloud Function as a URI in a blockchain contract. As such the URI can never be changed. So I am wondering if there is any reason the trigger (http address) for the function might ever be changed or if this is a guaranteed permalink?

If not then I'll setup a domain name and direct it there, but I would rather not have to do that if the link is guaranteed permanent. Any information in this regard would be super helpful.

I imagine they wouldn't change this just for fun since many services depend on those links, but of course an app can always be updated and unfortunately a smart contract cannot :(

Comment: I do not know the answer. However, I have not read anything anywhere that guarantees the URI will not change in the future. Changes are not likely short-term (< 36 months), but I would not build a long-term service that depends on that assumption. There are other factors that might occur that force you to abandon an endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs don't change unless you change the function name or region. In fact, you get to know the URL even before creating the function. They follow the same pattern:

```
https://[FN_REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/[FN_NAME]
```

[image]